# iOS scrollview adaption for landscape

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, landscape-portrait

I am using the following scrollview from a tutorial series. It works fine in portrait mode but the frame does not handle the switch to landscape mode. Is there a fast way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
    NSString *plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.displayRegion] ofType:@"plist"];
    self.SituationData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistFile];

    self.singleSituation = [SituationData objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath];

    self.SituationScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)]; //distinguishing between iphone 4 and 5 screen

    self.SituationScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.SituationScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.SituationScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.SituationScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //adding to the view
    [self.view addSubview:self.SituationScrollView];

    //getting the base indicator
    int baseNum = self.selectedIndexPath ;

    self.plistFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.displayRegion] ofType:@"plist"];
    self.auswahl = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:self.plistFile];

    self.SituationScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.SituationScrollView.frame.size.width *[self.auswahl count], self.SituationScrollView.frame.size.height);

    for (NSInteger i=1; i <= [[self auswahl] count]; i++){

        UIImage *situationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"main%@", [[self.auswahl objectAtIndex:i - 1] objectForKey:@"nat_num"]]];
        UIImageView *situationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:situationImage];

        UILabel *situationTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        situationTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.auswahl objectAtIndex: i - 1] objectForKey:@"species"]];
        [situationTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [situationTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UITextView *description = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        description.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.auswahl objectAtIndex: i - 1] objectForKey:@"description"]];
        [description setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [description setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [description setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


        situationView.frame = CGRectMake((320 * (i-1)) + SIT_IMG_X, 66, 94, 87);
        situationTitle.frame = CGRectMake((320 * (i-1)) + TOP_DATA_X, 250, 240, 14);
        description.frame = CGRectMake((320 * (i-1)) + DESC_X, DESC_Y, DETAIL_WIDTH, 100);


        [self.SituationScrollView addSubview:situationView];
        [self.SituationScrollView addSubview:situationTitle];
        [self.SituationScrollView addSubview:description];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use a global BOOL variable
```

BOOl isLandscape =NO;

```
while writing frames

    situationView.frame = CGRectMake(isLandscape?0:0, isLandscape?0:0, isLandscape?320:480 , isLandscape?480:320);
```

in orientation method write again

```
if(orientation == Landscape)

{

 isLandscape=YES;

}

else

{

isLandscape=NO;

}

    situationView.frame = CGRectMake(isLandscape?0:0, isLandscape?0:0, isLandscape?320:480 , isLandscape?480:320);
```

Check it as a sample it will work depending on it you can use

Answer (score 0):

A little googlefu revealed [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450726/uiscrollview-frame-size-issue-in-landscape-mode) in which Mike states loading the UIScrollView in the `viewWillAppear` method instead of the `viewDidLoad` method, then the UIScrollView should appear as desired.